# .net Parse() round float values

Tags: c#, .net

I found one very interesting thing about parsing a string into a float value. The case is that the string value is obtained from a database by using IDbReader  Here is an example:

```
IDbReader myReader;
...
string sValue = myReader.GetValue(0).ToString(); // 12.339123 for example in VS debug and watch
// the content of sValue is what I want to be at this point, but...
Single fValue = Single.Parse(sValue);
// Now the fValue is 12.34!
```

If I test just Parse for a constant string, the Parse method works fine:

```
string sValue = "12.339123";
Single fValue = Single.Parse(sValue);
// Now the fValue is 12.339123!
```

I am not sure why the content of sValue from IDbReader cannot be parsed as original value (as I can see from VS debug). It rounds the float value to a float value with 2 digits after decimal point. How can I get the original value?

How I can get the exactly same value back?

I am using .Net 2.0

Update: I tried to use GetXXX such as GetFloat or GetDecimal methods to get values directly to a float/decimal value.  Unfortunately, all those methods seem having similar rounding issue. Only GetValue() and forcing to string will get the exactly same string value as it is in the database. I thought I could do the conversion to a float or decimal value on .Net side, but the Parse() fails in my case. I am not sure why the rounding happen in Parse(). As some suggested the value are there, and it may be VS debug, watch or log caused rounding. However, when I tried to put the float value to a text box, it is rounded to 2 digits after decimal point. It is really a frustrating issue.

Comment: Not all `"12.339123"` are equal.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: In your first example, what is in `sValue` after the `.ToString()` call?

Comment: what is the exact class of the DataReader you get at runtime? I think you should use GetDecimal or other typed GetXXX methods not a GetValue on which you do a ToString and another cast to single later on...

Comment: the data type is NUMBER (Oracle)

Comment: In the case of using IDbReader, I think it should not be a matter at all. I forced the result to a string. But Parse() does not work as expected.

Comment: It matters if your value is being rounded before `Parse()` gets hold of it.

Comment: As I indicated in my updated question. I saw the result as a string as a un-rounded string value. This is a simplified version. I do log the result to a log file. The sValue before Parse() is the value I want, but the Parse() rounds the value.

Comment: I think that the Single.Parse method uses the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture object to determine the rules for parsing.  Perhaps your application that reads from the database is setting a specific culture that causes the number to be parsed to 2 fractional digits.  That might explain why you are not seeing the same result when you try to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: `> I do log the result to a log file`.  Which is where the problem is located, your logging code is no doubt rounding the value.

Comment: @HenkHolterman for an IEEE single there is only one value that gives 12.339123 when rounded to 6 places.

Comment: @Dr.Wily'sApprentice, I think that your analysis does make sense. Not sure if there is anyway to get the string back as float or Single value as it in the string.

Comment: @Davide Piras, I tried to use other GetXXX, but only GetValue and convert it to string will get the expected value. Other methods will round values to 2 digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're looking at that variable and seeing `12.34`. If I do the following in LINQPad:

```
Single.Parse("12.339123")
```

I get `12.33912`. And if I ask it to give me a string with the full round-trip precision:

```
Single.Parse("12.339123").ToString("r")
```

I get `12.3391228`, which is as close to exactly `12.339123` as you're going to get with a mere single-precision floating-point value.

Conclusion: you're using an imprecise means to inspect the variable's value. The variable itself is almost certainly fine, and holds just as precise a value as floating-point will allow; it's just that the debugger tooltip, or watch window, or logging library, or whatever it is you're using to look at that value, is only showing you a handful of digits.

Comment: I tried those cases with just constants or variables assigned with float values.  They work fine. However, when I get a value from IDbReader, the float value is rounded to 2 digits after decimal point. That's the puzzle I still cannot figure it out. Now I have to use string to store and present values in order to preserve their original values.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
string sValue = myReader.GetValue(0).ToString("F6");
```

Comment: But it's not useful in all cases.

Comment: sorry, call .ToString() here: float fValue = float.Parse(sValue.ToString("F6"));

Comment: True. the values in PL/SQL are all different float values or integer ones. I prefer to get value in whatever I see in PL/SQL tool.