# floating precision lost in float.Parse

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, floating-point

```
float s = float.Parse("10499.9705314636");
```

Now `s` has the value `10499.97`.

Is there a way to save all the precision digits?

Comment: Use `double` or `decimal`. Decimal will even preserver trailing zeros, while `double` simply offers better precision. If you are dealing with money, decimal is a must

Comment: Not using `float`, no. As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single), `float` has about 7 digits of precision.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509442/net-parse-round-float-values

Comment: Also note that `double` is faster for calculations but you *will* get rounding errors.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, `Decimal` has more precision than `Double`.. or were you saying that `Double` offers more precision than `Float` in your remark?

Comment: Double has more precision than float. Decimal offers even better precision *and* preserves trailing zeros.

Comment: FYI, the closest IEEE 32 bit binary float to 10499.9705314636 is 10499.970703125, the closest 64 bit is 10499.970531463599400012753903865814208984375. If neither of those is close enough, go decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to look into the [difference between float, double, and decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net). Pay special attention to the difference between a *binary* floating point type, and a *decimal* floating point type. Decimal data type is likely what you're looking for here, as float doesn't have enough significant digits to store the number you're trying to parse accurately.

Comment: OMG I dint know this till now. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try using a data type with a higher precision than `float`, such as `double`. The remaining digits of your value are truncated due to the size of the data type `float`:

```
double s = double.Parse("10499.9705314636");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Prints:

> 10499.9705314636

Answer (score 2):

You should try and use `decimal` instead.